# Merging touching polygons giving wrong result

Tags: c#, geometry, 2d, polygon, clipperlib

I'm trying to write a piece of code that given a list of polygons (defined as a list of lists of IntPoints) checks if any of them touch and if so merge them into a single polygon. In order to do this I have already tried the following two methods:

```
List<List<IntPoint>> output=new List<List<IntPoint>>();
output = Clipper.SimplifyPolygons(input,PolyFillType.pftPositive);
```

and

```
Clipper c = new Clipper();
c.AddPaths(input, PolyType.ptClip, true);
c.Execute(ClipType.ctUnion, output);
```

Now both of these merge the polygons together quite easily however they are a bit overzelous as any polygon open spaces are ignored and open areas are simply combined into a single polygon, meaning that something like this: 
[image: Sheer horror as a two polygons that are not touching are merged into a single square devoid of any meaning or life]

happens. Now this is obviously wrong as these two polygons do not touch each other. The same result occurs with both methods. The result would be the same as the input. Any idea how to fix this? The sollution does not have to use the clipper library (I'm not married to it) but I do need something that uses polygons that are defined by a list of points input is a List> where an Intpoint is just a struct containing an x and a y.

Edit I notice that this problem also occurs when there is no polygon inside of the other polygon, so the solution is always "filled"
edit edit: here is also an example of what input might be like

```
input[0][0]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -724
    Y: -472
input[0][1]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: 428
    Y: -472
input[0][2]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: 428
    Y: -472
  input[0][3]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: 428
    Y: 632
input[0][4]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: 428
    Y: 632
input[0][5]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -724
    Y: 632
input[0][6]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -724
    Y: 632
input[0][7]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -724
    Y: -472
input[0][8]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -88
    Y: -218
input[0][9]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -107
    Y: -218
input[0][10]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -107
    Y: -218
input[0][11]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -107
    Y: -209
input[0][12]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -107
    Y: -209
input[0][13]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -320
    Y: -172
input[0][14]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -320
    Y: -172
input[0][15]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -320
    Y: 132
input[0][16]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -320
    Y: 132
input[0][17]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -88
    Y: 173
input[0][18]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -88
    Y: 173
input[0][19]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -88
    Y: -201
input[0][20]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -88
    Y: -201
input[0][21]
{ClipperLib.IntPoint}
    X: -88
    Y: -218
```

The input this descripes is a square with a hole cut into it.

Comment: Anyone even know how best to describe this problem? Polygons in polygons being merged? Not allowing for enclaves?

Comment: I think I may have found the sollution but that will depend on the answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34263601/algoritm-for-translating-list-of-wallsections-into-coherent-polygon

Answer (score 3):

There needs to be a `PolyType.ptSubject`(missing from your code) and a `PolyType.ptClip` added to your `Clipper` before execution. Also you need to select the `ClipType` that will produce the result you want, as shown below:

```
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        clip = new List<List<IntPoint>>();
        clip.Add(pol2);

        input = new List<List<IntPoint>>();
        input.Add(pol1);

        output = new List<List<IntPoint>>();

        Clipper c = new Clipper();
        c.AddPaths(input, PolyType.ptSubject, true);
        c.AddPaths(clip, PolyType.ptClip, true);
        c.Execute(clipType, output);

        DrawPolygon(output, e.Graphics, Pens.Red);
    }
```

XOR:

[image]

Union:

[image]

Intersection:

[image]

Difference: `pol1` - `pol2`

[image]

Difference: `pol2` - `pol1`

[image]

Comment: I think the problem has more to do with an inproper input format than that?

Comment: I think that the addpaths would automatically add them as subjects since there, there are also more then 2 (and in some situations only 1) polygon.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the library needs some combination of the PolyTree version of the Execute method, and some more complicated build up of the polygons in the Clipper object, that takes into account whether the input contains holes.

It doesn't look like the green polygon with the hole is represented as just an array of points, it should be a PolyTree with an outer polygon and an inner hole polygon.

Comment: Any idea how I would approach that?

Answer (score -3):

Another thing you could look into is the Spatial datatypes introduced in SQL Server 2008 when handling geometric shapes.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry.stintersection.aspx

Geography is same URL but with sqlgeography instead of sqlgeometry

You can use the .STIntersects() == 1 and .STIntersection(AnotherShape) to retrieve the intersections. There are also other methods to give you the same results as above.

The benefit to this is that if you incorporate this with your database, you can utilize spatial indexes to make it even faster.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934196.aspx

Comment: Useful but this software does not include anything related to databases and I don't think it's a good idea to force people to also have a database installed.

Comment: I understand your concern but similarly to working with EntityFramework, you can use the classes that are included in the .NET framework (DbGeometry/DbGeography) and populate them manually. This doesn't require a database or even any kind of data access. It's just utilizing built in functionality of classes that were designed to make working with the spatial datatypes easier.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with what the OP is asking.