# Algorithm for translating list of wallsections into coherent polygon

Tags: c#, algorithm, geometry, 2d, polygon

I have a list of points that in pairs describe a polygon, like this:

<0,0><0,1><0,1><1,0><1,0><1,1><1,1><0,0> which is a square.  Note that each pair of points describes a line so our square is made up out of the lines

<<0,0><0,1>><<0,1><1,0>><<1,0><1,1>><<1,1><0,0>>

I do however have to draw these polygons which works fine when the points in question are all properly in order and there are no holes. Unfortunatly this sometimes goes wrong when the input is like

<0,0><0,1><1,1><0,0><0,1><1,0><1,0><1,1> and the resulting polygon is weird or when there are several holes in the

<0,0><0,2><0,2><2,0><2,0><2,2><2,2><0,0><1,1><1,1.5><1,1.5><1.5,1.5><1.5,1.5><1,1>

In these situations the naitive thing of drawing these polygons with a drawpoly(points) is not going to work.

This is in c# and the input is in reality a `List<GeoData>` where `GeoData` contains 2 points (and some other misq data). For the output I was thinking of making a List and a List> where the first set of points are the outer line and the second list is the holes, would that work? I do need to do some extra computations with the polygons other then just drawing but I think that will be easiest with a special list of holes.

Here is an example: 
 [image]

On the left is what I currently get on the right is the input.

Comment: Did you set the points in that order in the list and then you try to draw? Or someone provide that points?

Comment: I can order them (not that hard) but the problem is that if there are holes (especially multiple) then drawing them will fail as it tries to connect the holes together.

Comment: From your example I see that you draw a **single** polygon. You should call the method draw polygon (`drawpoly(points)`) multiple times for each separate polygon.

Comment: Yes I understand that, I'm mostly looking for the algoritm that allows me to do so (either by drawing the holes or or by clever splitting). I already have the clipperlib for some of these things so if I could use that then that might be useful.BtW in my example the green is the polygon I draw and the white is the holes that are placed within.

Comment: My current theory is that I will have to solve a cycle problem in the resulting graph to find all the polygons, is that right?

Comment: It should be quite easy. Make set of all points, assign lines to them. Then pick random point and follow lines to construct polygon. If any point remain, repeat to build another polygon. Only complication could be point in four or more lines, if possible.

Comment: Yhea working on that but there are some extra things to keep an eye on (point can touch so it has to be a graph ext.).

Answer (score 1):

From your example I see that you draw a **single** polygon. You should call the method draw polygon (`drawpoly(points)`) multiple times for each separate polygon.

I think it's easier to draw the *holes* instead the wall, respecting the principle [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

To do that you can store the polygons (holes) you want to draw in a list. If we do an analysis about data, we see that **bolded** data show the *begining* and the *end* of an polygon.

**<0,0>**<0,2><0,2><2,0><2,0><2,2><2,2>**<0,0>**
**<1,1>**<1,1.5><1,1.5><1.5,1.5><1.5,1.5>**<1,1>**

And we represent this in code, as shown below:

```
public List<List<GeoData>> Split(List<GeoData> points)
{
    List<List<GeoData>> polygons = new List<List<GeoData>>();
    GeoData firstPoint = null;
    List<GeoData> currentPolygon;

    foreach(var point in points)
    {
        if(firstPoint == null)
        {
            firstPoint = point;
            currentPolygon = new List<GeoData>();
            currentPolygon.Add(point);
        }
        else
        {
             currentPolygon.Add(point);
             if(point == firstPoint)
             {
                  firstPoint = null;
                  polygons.Add(currentPolygon);
             }
        }
    }
    return polygons;
}
```

Usage:

```
List<List<GeoData>> polygons = Split(points);

foreach(var polygon in polygons) 
{
    drawpoly(polygon);
}
```

Comment: Yes this was why I was proposing keeping a list of holes in the question however I'm mainly looking for a way to distil these holes from the figure given a set of line segments. So right now I have something like <0,0><0,1><0,1><1,0><1,0><1,1><1,1><1,1.5><1,1.5><1.5,1.5><1.5,1.5><1,1><1,1><0,0> which I need to seperate into two polygons.

Comment: If I understand good, you have a list of points and you need to split that list in multiple polygons (holes)?

Comment: Yes and this list contains pairs of points that descripte each individual line so <0,0><0,1><0,1><1,0><1,0><1,1>...  can be read as<<0,0><0,1>><<0,1><1,0>><<1,0><1,1>>....

Comment: That looks like it will work when all points are in order but one problem is that the points are not always in order (and do you happen to know a quick way of finding out which of the resuting polygons is the "mother" polygon and which are the holes?)

Comment: @Thijser I think you can find the *mother* using a `firstPoint` and a `secondPoint`. If `secondPoint` it's finded first, than you have a polygon.

Comment: @Thijser But.. again, the data really must be serialized in that way? You have a choice in this?

Comment: I don't have much choice in what order the data is given to my program, they come from an external program.

Comment: Hmm it looks like in order to solve this I will have to find all the simple cycles in a graph or do you know an easier way?